# Proving $f(x)$ is not a square in $k[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory

Let the field $k$ be algebraically closed, let $f(X) \in k[X]$ be a separable polynomial of degree at least $2$, let
$$
B = \frac{k[Y,X]}{(Y^2 - f(X))}
$$
and write $y,x$ for the images in $B$ of $Y$ and $X$, respectively.

I'm proving something where I'd like to use that $f(x)$ is not a square in $k[x]$, so I'm first trying to show why this is true. I know that since $f(X)$ is separable, it has no squares among its non-constant factors in $k[X]$. So I tried to do a proof by contradiction:

> Assume $f(x) = (g(x))^2$ for some $g(x)\in k[x]$. Now I want to show that $f(X)$ would have a square among its non-constant factors. But I'm not seeing how to go from $k[x]$ back to $k[X]$.

I know that if $f(X) = (g(X))^2$, then $f(x) = (g(x))^2$, but I'm not sure if it's valid to go back the other way. Any advice?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand. Aren’t the fields $k(X)$ and $k(x)$ isomorphic?

Comment: @Lubin you mean the rings $k[X]$ and $k[x]$? Come to think of it, you may be right. Let me work that out.

Comment: The polynomial rings are isomorphic, and the corresponding fraction fields likewise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suppose you want to know if it is possible to have $f(x)=g(x)^2$ in $k[x]$, hence in $B$.

This leads to $f(X)-g(X)^2\in (Y^2-f(X))$ in $k[X,Y]$. By taking the degree in $Y$ on both sides we get $f(X)=g(X)^2$ and this is not possible since $f$ is separable.

Answer (score 1):

A polynomial that is  a square cannot be separable over any field: if $f(X)=g(X)^2$ we get $f'(X) = 2g(X)g'(X)$, and $f,f'$ aren't coprime.